# Set focus from Drop down list to window on mouse hover on menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Here is a screen shot
[image]

i have a drop down list on my page.When i click on the drop down list it pops out and after that if i select on the Top Menu bar it extends as shown above unable to over ride the drop down list.
can any one throw some light on how to handle this issue.

**EDIT :**
I just created a 

#### jsfiddle Demo Link

  when we click on the drop down list first(and dont select anything) and den hover on the report menu tab the drop down list overlaps the menu.Dats the issue.

Here is the html code anywaz

```
<div class="Main_Nav">
<div id="globalNav">
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="HTMLID" class="first fourColumns">
        <div class="NavIcon_Administration">
        </div>
        <a href="#" title="Administration">Administration<span></span></a>
        <div class="pointer">
        </div>
        <div class="sub">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="title">System Management</li>
                    <li><a href='CallTypeMst.aspx'>Call Type</a></li>
                    <li><a href='AdmMenuMst.aspx'>Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href='AdmProfileMst.aspx'>Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href='AdmUserMst.aspx'>User</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li class="title">Settings</li>
                    <li><a href='GeneralSettings.aspx'>General</a></li>
                    <li><a href='ThresholdSetting.aspx'>Threshold</a></li>
                    <li><a href='RouteMaintenanceSettings.aspx'>Route Maintenance</a></li>
                    <li><a href='FraudCallSettings.aspx'>Fraud Call</a></li>
                    <li><a href='ClientDetails.aspx'>Client Config</a></li>
                    <li><a href='ManageRateSheetDashBoard.aspx'>RateSheet</a></li>
                    <li><a href='DefaultRoute.aspx'>Default Routing</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CallAlert.aspx'>Call Alert</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li id="HTMLID" class="first fourColumns">
        <div class="NavIcon_Operation">
        </div>
        <a href="#" title="Operations">Operations<span></span></a>
        <div class="pointer">
        </div>
        <div class="sub">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="title">Customer</li>
                    <li><a href='CustomerAdministration.aspx'>Administration</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CustomerRateSheetActivate.aspx'>Activate Rate Sheet</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CustomerRateActivationHistory.aspx'>Activation History</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CustomerRSCompare.aspx'>Compare RateSheet </a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li class="title">Carrier</li>
                    <li><a href='CarrierAdministration.aspx'>Administration</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CarrierRSCompare.aspx'>Compare Rate Sheet</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li class="title">LCR</li>
                    <li><a href='LCRRebuildNew.aspx'>Build LCR</a></li>
                    <li><a href='LCRRebuildHistory.aspx'>Build History</a></li>
                    <li><a href='LCRActivationNew.aspx'>Activate LCR</a></li>
                    <li><a href='LCRActivationHistory.aspx'>Activation History</a></li>
                    <li><a href='EditLCR.aspx'>Edit LCR</a></li>
                    <li><a href='LCRDownload.aspx'>Download LCR</a></li>
                    <li><a href='RouteBlocking.aspx'>Route Block</a></li>
                    <li><a href='LCRActivationForNewClient.aspx'>Synchronization</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li class="title">Fax & Inbound</li>
                    <li><a href='FaxSettings.aspx'>Fax Service</a></li>
                    <li><a href='InboundTollFreeAdd.aspx'>Add Inbound Number</a></li>
                    <li><a href='InboundTollFreeBulkUpload.aspx'>Inbound BulkUpload</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li class="title">Lerg & Network</li>
                    <li><a href='LergUpdation.aspx'>Lerg Administration</a></li>
                    <li><a href='NetworkMaster.aspx'>Network Administration</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li class="title">Maintenance</li>
                    <li><a href='RouteMaintenanceMst.aspx'>Route Maintenance</a></li>
                    <li><a href='FraudCallBlackList.aspx'>Fraud Call Black List</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li id="HTMLID" class="singleColumn">
        <div class="NavIcon_Reports">
        </div>
        <a href="#" title="Reports">Reports<span></span></a>
        <div class="pointer">
        </div>
        <div class="sub">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="title">Summary</li>
                    <li><a href='DailySummary.aspx'>Daily Summary</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CallStatus.aspx'>Call Status</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CallStatisticsReport.aspx'>Call Statistics</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CarrierRateSheetDashboard.aspx'>RateSheet Summary</a></li>
                    <li><a href='AuditLog.aspx'>Audit Log</a></li>
                    <li><a href='ManageLogFiles.aspx'>Log Files</a></li>
                    <li><a href='ServiceMonitor.aspx'>Service Monitor</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li class="title">Search</li>
                    <li><a href='CDRArchiveSearch.aspx'>CDR</a></li>
                    <li><a href='LCRSearch.aspx'>LCR</a></li>
                    <li><a href='LergSearch.aspx'>Lerg</a></li>
                    <li><a href='SearchCarrierRateSheet.aspx'>Carrier Rate Sheet</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CustomerRateSheetSearch.aspx'>Customer Rate Sheet</a></li>
                    <li><a href='FraudCallBlackListSearch.aspx'>Fraud Call Black List</a></li>
                    <li><a href='FaxSearch.aspx'>Fax</a></li>
                    <li><a href='InboundTollFreeSearchDelete.aspx'>Inbound</a></li>
                    <li><a href='RouteBlockSearch.aspx'>RouteBlock</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
                    </div></div>
                        <table align="right"><tr><td align="right">
    <select >
        <option>Option1</option>
        <option>Option2</option>
        <option>Option3</option>
        <option>Option4</option>
        <option>Option5</option>
    </select>
                        </td></tr></table>
```

And here is the CSS code

```
    .globalNav nav ul li
{
    display:;
}


:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: "";
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: "" "";
}

ul,
ol {
    margin: 0 0 1.357em 0;
    /*color: #2C2C2C;*/
}
.contentTable {
    margin: 0 0 1.357em 0;
}
.contentTable td {
    padding: 0 20px;
}
p.small {
    font-size: 0.786em; /* 11px */
    line-height: 1.727em;
    margin-bottom: 1.727em;
    color: #999;
}



#globalNav li {
    list-style: none;
}

/* 
Primary navigation
*/
#globalNav {
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
    height: 48px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 55000; 
    /*z-index: 9999;*/
}

* html #globalNav {
    background: url('../Images_v4/Master/NavMenu.png') no-repeat 0 -39px;
}
    * html .middleContent {
        z-index: 3000;
    }
    *:first-child+html .middleContent {
        z-index: 3000;
    }    
    #globalNav ul {
        width: 550px;
        height: 48px;
        line-height: 48px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        float: left;
    }

    #globalNav ul ul {
        height: auto;
    }

    #globalNav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
        #globalNav li {
            float: left;
            height: 48px;
            z-index:10;
        }
        #globalNav li.singleColumn {
            position: relative;
        }
            #globalNav li a {
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 14px;
                text-decoration: none;
                /*text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #198cb6;*/
                cursor: pointer;
                padding: 0 0 0 10px;
                float: left;
                outline: none;
                overflow: hidden;
                max-height: 48px;
            }
                * html #globalNav li a {
                    height: 48px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    padding-right: 10px;
                    position: relative;
                }
                *:first-child+html #globalNav li a {
                    height: 48px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    padding-right: 10px;
                    position: relative;
                }                
            #globalNav li.first a {
                padding: 0 0 0 0px;
            }        
                * html #globalNav li.first a {
                    padding: 0 10px 0 24px;
                }    
                *:first-child+html #globalNav li.first a {
                    padding: 0 0px 0 0px;
                }                                
            #globalNav li a span {
                height: 48px;
                padding: 0;
                padding-right: 10px;
                float: right;
            }
                * html #globalNav li a span {
                    position: absolute;
                    right: 0;
                    top: 0;
                }
                *:first-child+html #globalNav li a span {
                    position: absolute;
                    right: 0;
                    top: 0;
                }
                #globalNav li a:hover {
                    /*background: transparent url('../Images_v4/Master/NavMenu.png') no-repeat -300px -88px;*/
                }    
                #globalNav li.first a:hover {
                    padding-left: 0px;
                    /*background: transparent url('../Images_v4/Master/NavMenu.png') no-repeat 0 -88px;*/
                }        
                    * html #globalNav li.first a:hover {
                        padding-left: 24px;
                        /*background: transparent url('../Images_v4/Master/NavMenu.png') no-repeat 0 -88px;*/
                    }                            
                #globalNav li a:hover span {
                    /*background: transparent url('../Images_v4/Master/NavMenu.png') no-repeat right -88px;*/
                }    
                    #globalNav li.selected {
                        /*background: transparent url('../Images_v4/Master/NavMenu.png') no-repeat -300px -88px;*/
                    }

                    #globalNav li a:active {
                        /*background: transparent url('../Images_v4/Master/NavMenu.png') no-repeat -300px -137px;*/
                    }
                        * html #globalNav li.selected {
                            background: transparent;
                        }                    
                    #globalNav li.first a:active {
                        /*padding-left: 24px;
                        background: transparent url('../Images_v4/Master/NavMenu.png') no-repeat 0 -137px;*/
                    }
                    #globalNav li.first.selected {
                        /*background: transparent url('../Images_v4/Master/NavMenu.png') no-repeat 0 -88px;*/
                    }
                        * html #globalNav li.first a:active {
                            /*padding-left: 24px;
                            background: transparent url('../Images_v4/Master/NavMenu.png') no-repeat 0 -137px;*/
                        }
                    #globalNav li.selected span {
                        /*background: transparent url('../Images_v4/Master/NavMenu.png') no-repeat right -88px;*/
                    }

                    #globalNav li a:active span {
                        /*background: transparent url('../Images_v4/Master/NavMenu.png') no-repeat right -137px;*/
                    }
                        * html #globalNav li.selected span {
                            background: transparent;
                        }

#header div.middleContent div#globalNav div.searchfield {
    width: 165px;
    float: right;
    height: 48px;
    background: transparent url('../Images_v4/Master/NavMenu.png') no-repeat -586px -137px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

    * html #header div.middleContent div#globalNav div.searchfield {
        /* position: relative; */
        background: transparent url('../Images_v4/Master/NavMenu.png') no-repeat -586px -88px;
    }
    #header div.middleContent div#globalNav div.searchfield input {
        border: none;
        background: #fff;
        width: 140px;
        color: #666666;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        outline: none;
        height: 17px;
        margin-top: 16px;
        padding: 0;
        background: white;
        position: absolute;
    }

        html.rtl #header div.middleContent div#globalNav div.searchfield input {
            margin-right: 23px;
        }

        html[dir=rtl] #header div.middleContent div#globalNav div.searchfield input {
            margin-right: 23px;
        }        

#globalNav li .sub {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 61px;/*kp*/
    display: none;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    0%{ opacity: 0;}
    100%{ opacity: 1;}
}

#globalNav li:hover .sub {
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadein;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: once;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}

    #globalNav li .sub .menu {
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #b20041;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #777;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #777;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #777;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 24px 22px 22px 10px;
        overflow: hidden;

    } 
    * html #globalNav li .sub .menu {
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    *:first-child+html #globalNav li .sub .menu {

    }
        #globalNav li .sub .menu .otherFeatures {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 24px 0 0 0;
            clear: both;
            text-align: right;
            line-height: 14px;
        }
        * html #globalNav li .sub .menu .otherFeatures {
            padding: 20px 0 0 0;
        }
        *:first-child+html #globalNav li .sub .menu .otherFeatures {
            padding: 10px 0 0 0;
        }
            #globalNav li .sub .menu .otherFeatures a {
                text-shadow: none;
                float: none;
                font-weight: normal;
                height: auto;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                line-height: 14px;
                color: #787878;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            #globalNav li .sub .menu .otherFeatures a:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
                background: none;

            }
        #globalNav li .sub .menu ul {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 150px;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
            #globalNav li .sub .menu ul li {
                background: none;
                float: none;
                line-height: 21px;
                margin: 0;
                margin-bottom: 3px;
                padding: 0;
                height: auto;
            }
            #globalNav li .sub .menu ul li.title {
                line-height: 24px;
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #2c4d98;
                padding: 4px 0 5px 0;
                border-bottom:dotted 1px #af0040;
            }
                #globalNav li .sub .menu ul li.title a {
                    font-size: 18px;
                    color: #2c4d98;
                }
            #globalNav li .sub .menu ul li.separator {
                padding: 0 0 18px 0;
                margin: 0 0 18px 0;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
            }
                #globalNav li .sub .menu ul li a {
                    background: none;
                    float: none;
                    color: #787878;
                    text-shadow: none;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    padding: 4px 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    line-height: 19px;
                    /*font-weight: bold;*/
                }
                * html.rtl #globalNav .sub .menu ul li a {
                    display: inline-block;
                    line-height: 19px;
                    height: 19px;
                    padding: 0 0 4px 0;
                }
                *:first-child+html.rtl #globalNav .sub .menu ul li a {
                    display: inline-block;
                    line-height: 19px;
                    height: 19px;
                    padding: 0;
                }
                #globalNav li .sub .menu ul li a:hover {
                    background: none;
                    text-decoration: underline;
                    padding: 4px 0;
                }
                * html.rtl #globalNav li .sub .menu ul li a:hover {
                    padding: 0 0 4px 0;
                }
                *:first-child+html.rtl #globalNav .sub .menu ul li a:hover {
                    padding: 0;
                }
                #globalNav li .sub .menu ul li.sublink a {
                    font-weight: normal;
                }
#globalNav li.singleColumn .sub {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -180px;/*Customized- default:-98px*/
    top: 60px;
    width: 400px;
}
html.rtl #globalNav li.singleColumn .sub {
    left: auto;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: -98px;
}
* html.rtl #globalNav li.singleColumn .sub {
    left: auto;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: -98px;
}
#globalNav li.fourColumns .sub {
    left: 0;
    top: 60px;/*kp*/
}
* html #globalNav li.fourColumns .sub {
    width: ;
    top: 60px;/*kp*/
}
*:first-child+html #globalNav li.fourColumns .sub {
    width: ;
    top: 60px;/*kp*/
}
#globalNav li .pointer {
    height: 24px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 47px;/*kp*/
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 10000;
    background: url('../Images_v4/Master/NavMenu.png') no-repeat center 5px;
    font: 1px/1px monospace;
}
html.rtl #globalNav li .pointer {
    left: auto;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: -50%;
}
* html #globalNav li .pointer {
    top: 47px;/*kp*/
    left: -50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 21px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 -10px 0 -13px;
    padding: 0;
    background: url('../Images_v4/Master/NavMenu.png') no-repeat center 5px;
}
* html.rtl #globalNav li .pointer {
    left: auto;
    right: -50%;
    float: right;
}
*:first-child+html #globalNav li .pointer {
    top: 47px;/*kp*/
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 13px;
    left: -50%;
    margin: 0 -50%;
    padding: 11px 0 0 100%;
}
#globalNav li:hover .pointer {
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadein;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: once;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
#googleInput {
    border: 0;
    background: 0;
}

#awesomeHeader,
.awesomeHeader {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    color: #666666;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    height: 115px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background: #787878;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}

    body.business #awesomeHeader,
    body.business .awesomeHeader {
        background: #787878;
        margin: 0;
    }

    body.business #secure a, body.business #secure p {
        /*text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #4B465A;*/
    }

    #awesomeHeader #header,
    .awesomeHeader #header {
        width: 940px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
    }

.NavIcon_Administration
{
        background-image: url(../Images_v4/Master/NavIcon_Administration.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position:center center;
        float: left;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 45px;
        width: 35px;
}

.NavIcon_Operation
{
        background-image: url(../Images_v4/Master/NavIcon_Operation.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position:center center;
        float: left;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 45px;
        width: 35px;
}

.NavIcon_Reports
{
        background-image: url(../Images_v4/Master/NavIcon_Reports.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position:center center;
        float: left;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 45px;
        width: 35px;
}

.NavIcon_Settings
{
        background-image: url(../Images_v4/Master/NavIcon_Settings.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position:center center;
        float: left;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 45px;
        width: 35px;
}
#globalNav nav ul li:hover
{
    /*background: transparent url('../Images_v4/Master/NavMenu.png') no-repeat -300px -88px;*/
}
#globalNav nav ul li a:hover
{
    color:Black;
}

#globalNav nav ul li
{
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
.Main_Nav
{
        width: 600px;
        height:73px;
        float: right;
        min-width:400px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding:10px 5px 0px 20px;
        background-color:blue;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:0px 10px;
}​
```

Comment: Where is your code? We need to see the html and css. If you create a reduced example of the issue with http://jsfiddle.net that would be ever more helpful.

Comment: @tw16 updated question with a link to jsfiddle please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using jQuery you can

```
$('.fourColumns > a').mouseover(function() {
$('select').blur();
};
```

This may be wrong, but I hope it communicates my intent.

Cheers

UPDATE:
The following will work in the fiddle; perhaps you can use something similar on your site:

```
$('nav ul li').mouseover(function() {
$('select').hide();
});

$('nav ul li').mouseout(function() {
$('select').show();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BTCBL/29/

UPDATE AGAIN:
This alternative uses fewer characters and leaves the Select visible while collapsing the options:

```
$('nav ul li').mouseover(function() {
$('select').hide().blur().show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BTCBL/33/

Comment: what do u mean by fourColumns > a.It would be helpful if u can show something in jsfiddle.

Comment: what i mean by that was any element with an "a" tag that is a child of an element with "fourColumns" class. But this won't work as "Reports" doesn't have that class. I'll update my answer with a functioning option.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to set z-index of select tag and table (its parent) to 0? I don't see z-index property for select tag here. I am not sure,but it should work.

Comment: tried setting low z-index for Drop down but still not working